# What's the best objective function for the CartPole task?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, reinforcement-learning

I'm doing policy gradient and I'm trying to figure out what the best objective function is for the task. The task is the open ai CartPole-v0 environment in which the agent receives a reward of 1 for each timestep it survives and a reward of 0 upon termination. I'm trying to figure out which is the best way to model the objective function. I've come up with 3 possible functions:

```
def total_reward_objective_function(self, episode_data) :
    return sum([timestep_data['reward'] for timestep_data in timestep_data])

def average_reward_objective_function(self, episode_data):
    return total_reward_objective_function(episode_data) / len(episode_data)

def sum_of_discounted_rewards_objective_function(self, episode_data, discount_rate=0.7)
    return sum([episode_data[timestep]['reward'] * pow(discount_rate, timestep) 
        for timestep in enumerate(episode_data)])
```

Note that for the average reward objective function will always return 1 unless I intervene and modify the reward function to return a negative value upon termination. The reason I'm asking rather than just running a few experiments is because there's errors elsewhere. So if someone could point me towards a good practice in this area I could focus on the more significant mistakes in the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the last one (sum of discounted rewards), since the cart-pole problem is an infinite horizon MDP (you want to balance the pole as long as you can). [The answer to this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221402/understanding-the-role-of-the-discount-factor-in-reinforcement-learning) explains why you should use a discount factor in infinite horizon MDPs.

The first one, instead, is just an undiscounted sum of the rewards, which could be used if episodes have a fixed length (for instance, in the case of a robot performing a 10 seconds trajectory). The second one is usually used in finite horizon MDPs, but I am not very familiar with it.

For the cart-pole, a discount factor of 0.9 should work (or, depending on the algorithm used, you can search for scientific papers and see the discount factor used).

A final note. The reward function you described (+1 at each timestep) is not the only one used in literature. A common one (and I think also the "original" one) gives 0 at each timestep and -1 if the pole falls. Other reward functions are related to the angle between the pole and the cart.